# extracting variables issues

Tags: python-xarray, nco

Hi all I am having issues with both ncks and xarray

```
  ncks -C -O -4 -v time, R, B, G, PSAP.nc RGB.nc
```

I also tried

```
cdo selvar, R, B, G, data.nc RGB.nc
```

•   cdo not installed.

•   I am working on a a server I would have to go through help desk since I do not have permissions to use sudo apt-get install cdo

I have tons of variables I want to extract 3 variables alongside a time dimension

Comment: You can get around permissions by installing CDO using conda. It should only take a few minutes to install conda and CDO. https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html

Answer (score 1):

NCO seems to complain about your command's extra spaces that make the options look  like extra filenames. The arguments to `-v` should be comma-separated without spaces. Otherwise your command looks good. Try

```
ncks -C -O -4 -v time,Ba_R_combined,Ba_B_combined,Ba_G_combined PSAP.nc RGB_Absoprtion.nc
```

Comment: I ended up getting CDO installed. Using both CDO and NCO will be a god send. Thanks for the suggestion though. The night I looked into NCO I noticed you're pretty much an expect when I was googling around lol.